# Оптимизация SQL запроса (Copying To Tmp Table)

Tags: mysql, sql

Как можно оптимизировать данный запрос ?

```
SELECT InstanceID, max(Slot) as slot,
       (SELECT reseller
        FROM `mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_instance`
        WHERE`InstanceID` = mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_data.InstanceID) as 'reseller',
       (SELECT partner
        FROM `mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_instance`
        WHERE`InstanceID` = mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_data.InstanceID) as 'partner', 
       `Timestamp` AS 'date'
FROM `mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_data`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Timestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d') ='2016-12-18'
GROUP by DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Timestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d'),InstanceID 
ORDER BY InstanceID ASC
```

Профилирование:
[image: Профилирование запроса]

Comment: Как думаете, ваш запрос в одну строчку из 500+ символов удобочитаем?)

Comment: Попробовать вынести подзапросы с секции Select в From чтобы они не выполнялись для каждой записи.

Comment: Чего там пробовать? выносить обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Убрать подзапросы
2. Минимизировать использование полей в выражениях. (Не знаю насколько MySQL здесь отличается от MS SQL, но логично, что вычислить пару констант проще, чем применять преобразование к каждой строке)

   SELECT InstanceID, 
       max(Slot) as slot,
       i.reseller,
       i.partner,
       Timestamp AS 'date'
   FROM mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_data d
       JOIN mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_instance i ON i.InstanceID = d.InstanceID
   WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-18 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-18 23:59:59')
   GROUP by DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Timestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d'), InstanceID
   ORDER BY InstanceID ASC

Comment: Спасибо, "Copying To Tmp Table" в среднем уже занимает 350 ms
По факту экономия в 200 мс уже, как ещё можно оптимизировать запрос ? 
Выборка происходит из таблицы в которой храниться статистика, за день получается около 25 тысяч записей

Comment: @ArtemIvanko поменяйте местами поля в group by, что бы InstanceID был на первом месте. Возможно таким образом удастся избежать лишней пересортировки. А вообще приведите в вопросе текущий план выполнения (`explain ваш-запрос`)

Comment: Если поменять местами поля в group by, так что бы InstanceID был на первом месте то время выполнения запроса увеличивается на 100мс
план выполнения: http://image.prntscr.com/image/2c3688c3a9194a54a2a28e90c0cd4924.png

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT md.InstanceID, 
       max(md.slot) as 'slot',
       mi.reseller as 'reseller',
       mi.partner as 'partner', 
       md.Timestamp AS 'date'
FROM mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_data md, mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_instance mi
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(md.Timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d') ='2016-12-18'
AND md.InstanceID = mi.InstanceID
GROUP by 5, 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Проиндексировать InstanceID если то не PK в mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_data
Приложить план запроса, что б вам помогли правильно оптимизировать запрос.

Comment: Ваш вариант медленее чем вариант Denis'a
План запроса: http://image.prntscr.com/image/2c3688c3a9194a54a2a28e90c0cd4924.png

Comment: У вас идет перебор всех значений. Я так понимаю выборка должна быть по дням а даты в текущей таблице у вас вместе с временем. Есть предложение добавить или индексную таблицу (Таблица с InstanceID и  indexDate cвязь по id), или добавить в текущую таблицу поле формата y-m-d.

Comment: Заполнять либо с вашего ПО либо Тригером... Это ускорит запрос и мой, и запрос Denis. Так же это необходимо сделать, поскольку вы писали про 25к записей каждый день, и рано или поздно вы вернетесь к вопросу оптимизации.

Comment: Выражение `where somefunc(fieldname) = const` - это гарантированный fullscan. Потому что индекс-то вы явно построили не по `somefunc(fieldname)` а по `fieldname`. Используйте нормальный `where fieldname between const and const + interval '1 day'`. PS: order by 1 - deprecated.

Comment: @Мелкий Странно как то получается...
Даже при таком запросе все выполняется достаточно долго... http://prntscr.com/dlhkcn

Answer (score 0):

UDP после удаления индекса InstanceID для таблицы mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_data
 данный запрос выполняется за 0.1990 сек (В среднем 0.2300 сек)

```
SELECT 
d.InstanceID, 
max(d.Slot) as slot,
max(d.Online) as Online,
i.reseller,
i.partner,
Timestamp
FROM mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_data d
JOIN mod_TeamSpeak3Statistics_instance i ON i.InstanceID = d.InstanceID
WHERE Timestamp between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-20 00:00:00') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-12-20 23:59:59')
GROUP by DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(d.Timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d'), d.InstanceID
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

План запроса: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Профилирование: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие варианты оптимизации существуют ещё ?